# Flatlist warning Each child in a list should have a unique "key" only on first render

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

## problem

When the app gets loaded for the first time.The flatlist gives a waring and displays
"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.%s"

But this warning is only when it loaded for the first time. When saving the file again. Where the flatlist is located the warning disappears

### I have tried to fix it with by using the key extractor in different ways

1

```
<FlatList
  ref={flatListRef}
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item)=> item._id.toString()}
  renderItem={renderItem} 
/>
```

2

```
const keyExtractor = useCallback((item)=> item.postId,[])

<FlatList
  ref={flatListRef}
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item)=> item._id.toString()}
  renderItem={renderItem} 
/>
```

But the warning keeps on coming back on when the app is loaded for the first time.

### question

Whats the correct way to use the keyExtractor and how do to prevent the warning for happening.

### Solution

One of the render components triggered a map function where there was no key given.

Comment: How does your data look like and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your mapping any views using (.map) function if you are maping views then give the main container `key={index}`

Comment: Almost my problem. But got me looking at the right spot. I apparently had a map function in the render component where there was no key given. Which somehow only causes the problem on render. But when adding a key the warning was gone. So Thanks!

Comment: I got the idea about this issue because in initial learning days i was also stuck with the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with index like this

```
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

Comment: unfortunately i am still getting the warning when loading the app for the first time

Comment: also you can try to give the key to renderItem view  <View key={item._id.toString()}>

Comment: also not working. On further investigation i found out that the flat list get loaded multiple times. Could that be the cause of that's is only when the app is loaded for the first time. That that somehow the key gets used a second time during ?